# Mongodb match empty object in nested document

Tags: mongodb

I'm just wondering if this is possible to do in a single request?

Given

```
{
   _id: 1,
   foo: {
     fred: {},          // <- I want to remove empty keys like this
     barney: { bar: 1 } // <- But keep these keys
   }
}
```

Expected

```
{
   _id: 1,
   foo: {
     barney: { bar: 1 }
   }
}
```

I know how to do it in several requests, but I'm trying to understand MongoDB better.

---

**Note.** `fred` becomes empty in update command like `{ $unset: { "fred.baz": 1 } }` when `baz` is the last key in `fred`.

Maybe it is possible to remove it with its contents? But the command sender does not know, is there any other keys, except `baz` at the moment.

Answer (score 20):

You can search for empty embedded docs (`{ }`) and `$unset` them .. here's an example in the JS shell:

```
db.mycoll.update(
    {'foo.fred':{ }},
    { $unset: {'foo.fred':1} },
    false,  // upsert: no
    true    // multi: find all matches
)
```

Comment: How would you write is not { } meaning has fields in object ?

Comment: With query {'foo.fred':{ '$gt' : {} }} you would receive documents with non empty foo.fred attribute.